# shell program in c runs but gives 'lsh: no such file or directory.'

Tags: c

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define read_buffsize 1024
#define split_buffsize 64
#define delimiters "\t\r\n\a"
int main();
void loop(void);
char *readLine(void);
char **splitLine(char *command);
int start(char** args);
int execute(char **args);
```

I am trying to make a shell program in c. The program runs but when I type in a command and execute it says 'lsh:no such file or directory.' I put my function declarations int his question only because my code is about 150 lines of code. Example out put is shown below:

```
> ls -l
lsh: No such file or directory
> pwd
lsh: No such file or directory
>
```

Comment: Hard to tell since you haven't shown any definitions for your functions.

Comment: you could paste the function where you run the commands

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you do not have the program `lsh` installed. But `lsh` is an implementation of the SSH protocol. Here is a [Wikipedia desciption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsh). I think that `lsh` is not even an alternative to `bash` or `sh`. It just for logging into remote computers. Thus `lsh` does not know how to execute it (if you have it installed). Try to make the executable string (or `#define`) be `bash` not `lsh`.